# Set thumbnail image in UIImageView from URL

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

in my app i need to show some images to user. For every image there is a thumbnail which is created by the server every time someone uploads a picture.

Now what i want is that when i'm showing the image in the UIImageView, i want to first set the thumbnail image (a very light weight image almost 15kb) and then when the normal image has been downloaded show it in the same UIImageView.

I know there are some 3 party library that can do this, but the problem is that for both the thumbnail and the normal size picture i just got the URL.

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to do it using 3th party library [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke)

Here is the code

```
Nuke.loadImage(with: URL(string: post.thumble_url), into: postPicture) { [weak postPicture] response, _ in
            postPicture?.image = response.value
            if postPicture != nil {
                Nuke.loadImage(with: URL(string: self.post.picture_url), into: postPicture!)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create your UIImageView, automatically start the process of downloading the thumbnail + the image. Normally, the thumbnail should be downloaded first so just do: `imageView.image = MyThumnailUIImage` and when the full image is downloaded, simply do: `imageView.image = MyFullUIImage`

To be more usefull you could create a UIImage custom class. You could call a method and this method should to all the stuff for you (download the 2 images, handle the logic of displaying the thumbnail before the full image, downloading the image, ...)

I hope it has help you!